# WooCommerce: Show Confirming Message before removing item in the cart

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show a confirmation message when you removing the product on the WooCommerce cart. I can't find any code or solution for it.

[image: Screenhost]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add below code in your child theme js.

```
<script>

    jQuery( function($) {       
    $('.remove').click( function( event ) {
        if( ! confirm( 'Are you sure you want to remove product?' ) ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }  

    });
});
</script>
```

I have tested the code and its working for me

Comment: I added `event.stopPropagation(); ` on the code and it works. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @AlexisCartago - that works, `event.preventDefault();` still removes the item from cart if you click cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
if(confirm("Are you sure want to delete? ")){
 //logic to remove your product.
}
```

Thanks.