# Confirmation Message on removing item from the WooCommerce cart not working as expected

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WordPress and WooCommerce plugin. I want WooCommerce to show a confirmation message on removing an item from the cart. I am using the below Javascript code but it doesn't work properly as it has the below 2 issues.
1-When the confirmation message shows up, the item will be removed whether I press to confirm or cancel. It shouldn't remove the item if I press "cancel."
2-The confirmation message shows up on removing the first item from the cart, but it doesn't work when I try to remove another item.

My Website: https://coveti.com/shop/

```
<script>

    jQuery( function($) {       
    $('.remove').click( function( event ) {
        if( ! confirm( 'Are you sure you want to remove product?' ) ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }  

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You are not hooking to proper event - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342148/list-of-js-events-in-the-woocommerce-frontend . Your problem as you mention that woocoomerce will execute its event w/e you have custom click or not :)

Comment: I have changed the event to removed_from_cart but it still not working

Comment: If you are looking this code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54398366/woocommerce-show-confirming-message-before-removing-item-in-the-cart its mention that you should use stopPropagation instead

Comment: When i used stopPropagation it doesn't work at all